# Java multiple threads give very small perfomance gain

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I wanted to learn parallel programming for speeding up algorithms and chose Java.
I wrote two functions for summing `long` integers in array - one simple iterating through array, second - dividing array to parts and sum up parts in separated threads.

I expected to be logical a roughly 2x speed up using two threads. However, what I've got is only 24% speed up. Moreover, using more threads, I don't get any improvement (maybe less 1%) over two threads. I know that there should be thread creation/joining overhead, but I guess it shouldn't be that big.

Can you please explain, what I'm missing or where is error in code?
Here is code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;


public class ParallelTest {


public static long sum1 (long[] num, int a, int b) {
    long r = 0;
    while (a < b) {
        r += num[a];
        ++a;
    }
    return r;
}

public static class SumThread extends Thread {
    private long num[];
    private long r;
    private int a, b;

    public SumThread (long[] num, int a, int b) {
        super();
        this.num = num;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public void run () {
        r = ParallelTest.sum1(num, a, b);
    }

    public long getSum () {
        return r;
    }
}


public static long sum2 (long[] num, int a, int b, int threadCnt) throws InterruptedException {
    SumThread[] th = new SumThread[threadCnt];
    int i = 0, c = (b - a + threadCnt - 1) / threadCnt;

    for (;;) {
        int a2 = a + c;
        if (a2 > b) {
            a2 = b;
        }
        th[i] = new SumThread(num, a, a2);
        th[i].start();
        if (a2 == b) {
            break;
        }
        a = a2;
        ++i;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < threadCnt; ++i) {
        th[i].join();
    }
    long r = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < threadCnt; ++i) {
        r += th[i].getSum();
    }
    return r;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final int N = 230000000;
    long[] num = new long[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        num[i] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(1, 9999);
    }

    // System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

    long timestamp = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(sum1(num, 0, num.length));
    System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - timestamp);

    for (int n = 2; n <= 4; ++n) {
        timestamp = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(sum2(num, 0, num.length, n));
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - timestamp);
    }


}
}
```

EDIT: I have i7 processor with 4 cores (8 threads).
Output given by code is:

```
1149914787860
175689196
1149914787860
149224086
1149914787860
147709988
1149914787860
138243999
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program is probably main memory bandwidth limited with just two threads, as it's a small loop, that fetches data almost as fast as ram can supply data to the processor.

Comment: That means, if I had more CPU-intensive task in loop, then I'll have better perfomance gain with more threads?

Answer (score 3):

I can think of a number reasons why you might not get as much speedup as you are expecting.

1. Thread creation overheads are substantial.  Thread `start()` is an expensive operation, which entails multiple syscalls to allocate a thread stack and its "red-zone" and to then create the native thread.
2. The N threads will not all start at the same time.  That means that the time to complete the parallel part of the computation will be approximately the end-time of the last thread - the start-time of the the first time.  That will be longer than the time for one thread takes to do its part of the work.  (By N-1 times the thread creation time ...)
3. The N threads are (basically) doing a serial scan of N disjoint sections of the array.  This is memory bandwidth intensive, AND the way that you are scanning means that the memory caches are going to be ineffective. Therefore, there is a good chance that performance is limited by the speed and bandwidth of your system's main memory hardware.